# Python: Return 5 most frequent in a line of text

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to write a function that will take a line of text and return the top 5 most frequent words. If two of the same words have the same frequency, it is to return it by alphabetical order. Using the Counter from collections:

```
def top5_words(text):
    top5 = {}
    freq = Counter(text.split()).most_common(5)
    for i in freq:
        top5[i[0]] = i[1]
    return sorted(top5.items())[:5]
```

which does return `[('a', 1), ('one', 3), ('racehorse', 1), ('two', 2), ('was', 2)]` but i would like to return it by the word. Example: `['one', 'two', 'was', 'a', 'racehorse']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`most_common()` already return the items in order, so:

```
def top5_words(text):
    freq = Counter(text.split()).most_common(5)
    return [word for word, _ in freq]
```

would do what you want.